# Is a Given Binary Tree a Valid BST?

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

If a Tree is BST. then the inorder traversal must give us a sorted array.
And If the array is sorted then the given tree must be a BST
then why is this code failing

Thanx in Advance

```
void getInorder(vector<int> &inorder, TreeNode* A){

    if(A == NULL)
        return;
    getInorder(inorder,A->left);
    //cout<<A->val<<" ";
    inorder.push_back(A->val);
    getInorder(inorder,A->right);
}

int Solution::isValidBST(TreeNode* A) {
    //If it is a valid BST //Then its inorder Must be a sorted array;
    vector<int> inorder;

    if(A == NULL)
        return 0;

    getInorder(inorder,A);

    // for(int a:inorder)
    //     cout<<a<<" ";

    cout<<endl;
    return is_sorted(inorder.begin(), inorder.end()) == true ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Output
1 : It is a BST , 
0 : Not a BST

```
Failing Test Case :

     2
   /   \
  1     2
```

Its InOrder Traversal is: 1,2,2 (Is Sorted) 
MyCode O/P : 1 , Expected O/P : 0

Reason: (It's Not a BST, Because Right Sub tree
must have a value greater than Root, in this case, it is equal to root)

It Fails for Duplicated Values if Present in some order.

Comment: Could you please edit you question to explain how the code is "failing". Is it returning 1 when it is not a valid BST? Is it returning 0 when it is valid?

Comment: It's entirely possible that your input tree does not have the shape you think it has.

Comment: Why are you using `int` as a pseudo-boolean when there is a `bool` type?

Comment: @AndrewShepherd its now edited

Comment: @HiteshVerma: You still haven't given us enough. If it is "not working", then you must demonstrate this with an example. What data are you passing in? What result does this specific data give you? What happens if you step through this code with a debugger?

Comment: @AndrewShepherd Thank You for your insight, I have Updated the Question

Comment: There is no problem here to solve. The binary search condtion is <=, not <. Your claim that it doesn't allow duplicates is false.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `{1, 2, 2}` is actually a sorted list. Hence, `std::is_sorted` returns true for such an array. Here is a small example for you to experiment with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> mtmd = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5};
    std::cout << std::is_sorted(mtmd.begin(), mtmd.end()) << std::endl;

}
```

The output is `true`, which should be. The best solution is implementing your own `is_sorted`.

Comment: The problem is that the tree really is a BST, contrary to the OP's claim.

Comment: Obviously it is. Nonetheless, apparently he wants his program to return false for this case for whatever reason. What confuses me is the -1 I got on this answer.

Comment: Because the problem is not that {1,2,3} is actually a sorted list. The problem is his wrong definition and incorrect expectation.